# How can I improve my C# code to read data from MS Access into a 2d-array?

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, ms-access

My C# code below works however it takes close to an hour to process 180,000 rows of data. I'm looking for ways to improve performance. Is there a faster or better way to increase the array as new data is read or could the SQL statement be more efficient? Thanks.

```
int row = 0;
string[,] timeSeriesData = new string[row, colSize];
using (OleDbConnection AccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn))
{
    OleDbCommand cmdGetData = AccessConn.CreateCommand();
    cmdGetData.CommandText = sqlSELECT;

    AccessConn.Open();
    OleDbDataReader thisReader = cmdGetData.ExecuteReader();
    while (thisReader.Read())
    {
        string[,] tempArray = new string[row + 1, colSize];
        Array.Copy(timeSeriesData, tempArray, timeSeriesData.Length);
        timeSeriesData = tempArray;

        timeSeriesData[row, 0] = thisReader.GetDateTime(0).ToOADate().ToString();
        for (int j = 1; j < colSize; j++)
        {
            if (thisReader.IsDBNull(j))     
            {
                timeSeriesData[row, j] = "-999";  
            }
            else
            {
                timeSeriesData[row, j] = Convert.ToString(thisReader[j]);
            }
         }
         row++;
    }
    thisReader.Close();
    AccessConn.Close();
}
```

My SQL statement is usually something like this:

```
SELECT [TimeStamp], IIF([CH1Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH1Avg_Qual]=0, [CH1Avg], NULL) AS Col1, 
IIF([CH2Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH2Avg_Qual]=0, [CH2Avg], NULL) AS Col2, 
IIF([CH3Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH3Avg_Qual]=0, [CH3Avg], NULL) AS Col3, 
IIF([CH7Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH7Avg_Qual]=0, [CH7Avg], NULL) AS Col4, 
IIF([CH9Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH9Avg_Qual]=0, [CH9Avg], NULL) AS Col5, 
IIF([CH10Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH10Avg_Qual]=0, [CH10Avg], NULL) AS Col6, 
IIF([CH11Avg_Qual] IS NULL OR [CH11Avg_Qual]=0, [CH11Avg], NULL) AS Col7 
FROM [DataTable] ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

Comment: Just running the SQL directly in Access, how long does it take?

Comment: If your code actually works, but you are looking for a peer review, you probably want [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Please answer the question posted by @NexTerren, then we possibly would be able to provide you with some recommendations. Best regards,

Comment: @Nex Terran; it takes about 1 sec to run in Access.

Comment: @ Tieson T.; thanks for this, i didn't know that existed. It will be very helpful in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BobRodes for pointing me towards DataTable. The code below improved performance on one dataset from 18 min previously to 7 sec using a DataTable :) The code is a lot simpler too.

```
DataTable timeSeriesDataDT = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection AccessConnDT = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmdGetDT = new OleDbCommand(sqlSELECT, AccessConnDT))
    {
        AccessConnDT.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdGetDT);
        adapter.Fill(timeSeriesDataDT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a lot of extra overhead in the round trip between the DB and the data reader.  You're marshaling the data line by line through the connection, and that's usually the slowest part of the process.

You should be better off using a DataSet, pulling all the records into it, and then iterating the DataSet and building your array.  The DataSet will be in local storage so access should be faster.

Another alternative is to build the result you want using Access VBA and store it in a table.  Then, just pull the whole table from Access, again using a DataSet.  This would be preferable if you were using a small subset of the 180,000 records (I believe that isn't the case here), since you wouldn't have to truck all the records into the DataSet before you iterated them.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The machine running the code sits on the same machine which holds the Access database. Not sure if this helps with your query about the trip between the two. <br/> <br/>

Comment: Yes, reading line by line seems slow. I am new enough to programming so array's is what i know. Since posting i have come across Nested Lists but your DataSet suggestion has lead me onto DataTable and both look more appropriate than Nested Lists. I am assuming the data came be placed into either in one go and therefore no need to read line by line adding into an array that needs to be increased each time too? I will look into both.

Comment: I think i'll pass on the Access VBA suggestion. I usually need the whole table each time but also i think i need to bit the bullet and move to a proper database like MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: Yeah, the VBA suggestion is a bit "out there."  But again, reading line by line per se isn't the slow part, it's *marshaling* (basically passing) *each line across process boundaries* that's slow.  Suppose you had to send 1000 records to someone via snail mail.  What you're doing is analogous to putting each record in a separate envelope and mailing it separately, rather than putting 1000 records in an envelope and mailing them all at one go.  That takes a lot more time, no matter what someone is doing with the records at the other end.

Comment: And, while your assumption is correct about the DataTable, there's nothing stopping you from iterating the table and populating an array with it line by line as before.  It should still go much faster for the reason in my last comment.  It may be extra work in the end, but if you already have code that uses the array, it's less work to derive your array from the DataTable.